# asp .net imagebutton get by id with repeater / double event clicks

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a list that shows menus and also have a button to add a new item, using a dialog.

I want to edit with imagebutton and I wanna use dialog with image button, but the repeater makes image button id increment every time so the its name change and the script can't find it by Id.

I made `onclientclick` event to open dialog also I have `click` event for getting the Id of the row. So I have 1 `onclientclick` and  1 regular `click` event. When I click the image button dialog appears for 3 seconds and then it goes. How can i fix this problem ? I think its because of the 2 click event handlers, but I can't get the button via Id; what should i do?

note : Btw I tried to pick id from repeater which comes in id++ format. And deleted onclientclick and gave it button Id click but nothing changed looks like its not because of 2 click event handlers. Still when i click dialog comes and in a few sec it goes. any help ?

```
<script>     

  $(function () {

     $("#dialog-form").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 300,
          width: 350,
          modal: true,
        appendTo: AddForm,
      });



      $("#create-user")
        .button()
        .click(function () {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");

        });

      $("#dialog-form-edit").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 300,
          width: 350,
          modal: true,
          appendTo: AddForm,
      });




   });



  </script>
```

```
<div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">




        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE & BREADCRUMB-->
                <h3 class="page-title">
                MFT Haber Scripti V1  <small>Admin Paneli</small>
                </h3>
                <ul class="page-breadcrumb breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="pull-right">

                    </li>
                    <li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- END PAGE TITLE & BREADCRUMB-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE HEADER-->

        <div class="clearfix">

 <!-- BEGIN EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
                <div class="portlet box blue" >
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Düzenleme Tablosu

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <div class="table-toolbar">
                            <div class="btn-group">


                            <input type="button" value="Yeni Ekle +" Id="create-user" class="btn green"   />    

                            </div>
                            <ul style="float:right">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Seçilenleri Sil" BackColor="Red" CssClass="btn green" OnClick="Button7_Click" />
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="MenuDiv" >
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>

                              Seç  

                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Baslik
                            </th>


                            <th>
                                Edit
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Delete
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                                                      <asp:Repeater runat="server"     ID="repMasterMenu"><ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  /></td>
                            <td>
                                <%#Eval("MenuName") %>
                            </td>


                            <td>


                               <asp:ImageButton ID="Duzen" runat="server" OnClientClick="$('#dialog-form-edit').dialog('open');"   ImageUrl="~/admin/img/duzenle_16x16.gif"  CommandArgument=<%#Eval("Id") %>   onclick="Duzenle" Width="10px"  />

                                <!--<a href="#" class="btn default btn-xs purple"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>-->
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="Sil" ImageUrl="~/admin/img/sil_16x16.gif" runat="server" CommandArgument=<%#Eval("Id") %> onclick="sil" width="10px"/>

                                                                                <!--    <a href="#" class="btndefault btn-xs black"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</a>-->
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                                      </ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!-- END EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->

                 </div>
     <div id="dialog-form" >
 <p>All form fields are required.</p>



 <fieldset>
<label>Name</label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="name"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

```
</div>

           <div id="dialog-form-edit" >
  <p>All form fields are required.</p>



<fieldset>
<label>Name</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="add me baby" OnClick="addmebaby_Click_click" />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="AdminId" runat="server" />
</fieldset>

    </div>



</div>



<!-- END CONTENT -->

  <!-- END CONTAINER -->

 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: He means your markup formatting is a mess, and not easy to follow.

Comment: Yea I'm new to here Couldnt figure it out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

"the repeater makes image button id++ every time"

This is how Repeaters (and controls based on them) work. Change to using a class for jQuery selection instead.

Comment: I know thats how repeaters work =) I was explainin why ı couldnt get dialog by image button Id . what do u mean by change using a class for jquery ? can u explain more plz ?

Comment: Btw I tried to pick id from repeater which comes in id++ format. And deleted onclientclick and gave it button Id click but nothing changed looks like its not because of 2 click event handlers. Still when i click dialog comes and in a few sec it goes. any help ?